# Solving for a definite integral using a functional relation

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ satisfy the functional equation $$x = f(x)e^{f(x)}$$Then find the value of $$\int_{0}^{e}f(x)dx$$

My attempt:

$$\int_{0}^{e}f(x)dx$$
Using by - parts,
$$=[xf(x)]_{0}^{e}-\int_{0}^{e}xf'(x)dx$$
Now, using the given relation, solving the integral
$$\int_{0}^{e}xf'(x)dx = \int_{0}^{e}f(x)f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx$$
Making a substitution by taking $t = e^{f(x)}$, we get
$$[xf(x)-f(x)e^{f(x)}+e^{f(x)}]_{0}^{e}$$
Which is equal to $$\boxed{=f(e)-f(e)e^{f(e)}+e^{f(e)}-1}$$
The problem is that the answer is not given in terms of $f(e)$.

I needed some help simplifying the answer I got.

Comment: Note that $f(e)=1$. Also, the correct expression will be $$ \color{red}{ef(e)}-f(e)e^{f(e)}+e^{f(e)}-1. $$

Comment: Can you provide an explanation, I tried finding $f(e)$ but I do not get 1

Comment: When you plug $x = e$ and write $y = f(e)$, then the equation becomes $$e = ye^{y}.$$ Also, since the function $z \mapsto ze^z$ is strictly increasing on $z \geq 0$, this equation has a unique non-negative solution. Finally, we know that $y = 1$ simply works. So by the uniqueness, $f(e)=1$.

Comment: ohky thank you soo much